# PHP Parse JSON [HARD]

Tags: php, json, parsing

I have this script like this:

```
$jsonItems = file_get_contents('http://media1.clubpenguin.com/play/en/web_service/game_configs/paper_items.json');
$objDecode = json_decode($jsonItems, true);
foreach($objDecode as $item){
//Do something
}
```

That script works. How can I do it with this file without naming all the property names because there is over 100, i think: http://media1.clubpenguin.com/play/en/web_service/game_configs/paths.json

Please help me

Comment: What do you try to do? your code is enough for getting the data into PHP array

Comment: The links are different. The hard is this: http://media1.clubpenguin.com/play/en/web_service/game_configs/paths.json, easy one is this: http://media1.clubpenguin.com/play/en/web_service/game_configs/paper_items.json I got the easy one working.

Comment: ok, but what are you trying to do with that? are the `local` `global` and `links` keys known and will always exist?

Comment: I want to parse it but it has to many property names

Comment: just "parsing" won't give you anything - what are you intended to do with the data? what is the meaning of the keys?

Comment: I want download the SWFs.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the SWF links will always be in the inner objects in this data set - you can do that (an optional second check for the extension in the link may be required if not all of the links are SWF files)

```
$json = file_get_contents("http://media1.clubpenguin.com/play/en/web_service/game_configs/paths.json");
$data = json_decode($json,true);

foreach($data as $type=>&$links){
    foreach($links as &$link){
        //$link is the link - do what ever you want here
            //if needed check for SWF extension in the link here
    }
}
```